# How do I plot the graph of `res ` for different `epsilon` in the same plot?

Tags: r

I want to plot function `res`  for different value of `epsilon=0.1, 0.2,0.3,0.9` in the same plot in R.

My setting is that

```
#make this example reproducible
set.seed(1001)
n <- 500
#Sample GOE random matrix
A <- matrix(rnorm(n*n, mean=0, sd=1), n, n) 
G <- (A + t(A))/sqrt(2*n)
ev <- eigen(G)
l <- ev$values
v <- ev$vectors

#size of multivariate distribution
mean <- rep(0, n) 
var <- diag(n)

#simulate bivariate normal distribution
initial <- MASS::mvrnorm(n=1000, mu=mean, Sigma=var) #ten random vectors
#normalized the first possible initial value, the initial data uniformly distributed on the sphere
xmats <- lapply(1:1000, function(i) initial[i, ]/norm(initial[i, ], type="2"))

#define my function
h1t <- function(t,x_0) {
  h10 <- c(x_0 %*% v[, n])
  denom <- vapply(t, function(.t) {
    sum((x_0 %*% v)^2 * exp(-4*(l - l[n]) * .t))
  }, numeric(1L))
  abs(h10) / sqrt(denom)
}
```

For `1000` initial value `x_0` from normal distribution (I put them in a matrix `xmats`), I can plot all value of `t` so that `h1t=epsilon` for `epsilon=0.9`.

```
#set epsilon=0.9
find_t <- function(x, epsilon = 0.9, range = c(-500, 500)) {
  uniroot(function(t) h1t(t, x) - epsilon, range,
          tol = .Machine$double.eps)$root
}

res <- lapply(xmats, find_t)
```

```
plot(density(unlist(res)), xlim = c(0, 300),col = "red",
     main = "Fix epsilon=0.9. Density of tau_epsilon for different initial value for n=500")
```

I got:[image]

**Question: How do I plot the graph of `res`  for different `epsilon` in the same plot?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by applying your function to the parameter. I called the result `find_t03` and call `lines` after the `plot` call with this new result.

I have added `ylim` to the plot and also added a break in the title.

```r
#set epsilon=0.9
find_t <- function(x, epsilon = 0.9, range = c(-500, 500)) {
  uniroot(function(t) h1t(t, x) - epsilon, range,
          tol = .Machine$double.eps)$root
}
#set epsilon=0.3
find_t03 <- function(x, epsilon = 0.3, range = c(-500, 500)) {
  uniroot(function(t) h1t(t, x) - epsilon, range,
          tol = .Machine$double.eps)$root
}

res <- lapply(xmats, find_t)
res03 <- lapply(xmats, find_t03)

plot(density(unlist(res)), xlim = c(0, 200),
     ylim=c(0, 0.2),col = "red",
     main = paste0("Fix epsilon=0.9 (red) and 0.3 (black).",
                   "\n", "Density of tau_epsilon for different initial value for n=500"))
lines(density(unlist(res03)), ylim = c(0, 1000))
```

[image]